# Gradle complains about bracket

Tags: gradle

I got really strange behavior in Gradle. I didn't change anything and it stop works.

It show this error:

```
startup failed:
build file 'D:\project\modules\view\build.gradle': 45: expecting ')', found '}' @ line 45, column 1.
   }
   ^

1 error

Open File
```

This is how my gradle.build looks like:
[image]

And this is my pathingJar task, I have also no idea why it's marked as yellow (it wasn't before and i'm pretty sure i didn't change anything)

[image]

Does someone know an reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The if in `boot` is missing a `)`

```
if(Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) // the last ')' was missing
{
    // code omitted
}
```